# How many fled to the Cities of Refuge?

Tags: history, city-of-refuge

Do we know how many people (accidental murderers) took advantage of the Cities of Refuge (Deuteronomy 4:41-43)?  Perhaps the size of the cities would put an upper limit on that number, so do we know their size(s)?

Comment: E.g. how big was Hebron in 600BCE? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebron#First_Jewish_period . Say, couple of tens of thousands, so how you calculate the refugees?

Comment: @AlBerko  Did you glean the size of the archeological findings from the link you provided?  If not, what is the source of your estimate of 20,000.  In any case, some residents must have provided government services and others food.  So I would guess the percent that fled there was much less than the total population.

Comment: IIRC many were levi’im- they were Levi cities

Comment: This is a great question, and one that could be answered with some sort of ballpark figure based on what has been documented. For example, were there generally people arriving all hours of the day and night, so someone living in a city of refuge could hop over to the city gates pretty much any time outside of Shabbat and meet the latest new killers moving in? Was this exile extremely uncommon, such that a city resident might see one or two killers arrive during their lifetime? Was it somewhere in between?